# Activity has leaked, but cannot fix it

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I used LeakCanary to test my app. It shows a leak, but I cannot fix it.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

private TextView splashTime;
private Long showTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    init();
}

public void init() {
    showTime = 1L;
    splashTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.splash_time);
    splashTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enterApp();
        }
    });
    splashTime.setText(getString(R.string.splash_time, showTime));
    Log.d("splash", "init");
}

public void enterApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}}
```

And the Canary Log is here:

```
D/LeakCanary: In com.less.haku.hcomic:1.0:1.
                 * com.less.haku.hcomic.SplashActivity has leaked:
                 * GC ROOT static android.app.Instrumentation.mRecommendActivity
                 * references android.app.Instrumentation$RecommendActivity.mTarget
                 * leaks com.less.haku.hcomic.SplashActivity instance

                 * Reference Key: f4ea7ad3-a212-439f-ba67-3557823b07e9
                 * Device: Meizu Meizu m2 note m2 note
                 * Android Version: 5.1 API: 22
                 * Durations: watch=5014ms, gc=176ms, heap dump=2598ms, analysis=23065ms
```

I have no idea about how it happened, the activity is very simple, no handler, no inner class. And I don't understand the canaryLog, how to trace the problem? Thanks for help

I used string.xml to connect the string. All the string.xml code is here:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">HComic</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="splash_time">less %1$ds</string>
</resources>
```

SplashActivity is the firstActivity, in manifest code :

```
<activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I test this in many cases, maybe it caused by my phone, it didn't leak in emulator, i will test it in some other android phones.

Comment: What happen when using `getString(R.string.splash_time)` ?

Comment: Problem is here `splashTime.setText(getString(R.string.splash_time, showTime));`

Comment: show us your code in `getString(R.string.splash_time, showTime)`

Comment: I used string.xml to connect the string.  All  the string.xml code is here: <resources>
    <string name="app_name">HComic</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="splash_time">less%1$ds</string>
</resources>

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the call of SplashActivity. Who call SplashActivity?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Meizu FlymeOS. just exclude it. details see my [PR](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/pull/596)

If you cannot wait this PR to be merged, you could do following to exclude this leak:

```
ExcludedRefs excludedRefs = AndroidExcludedRefs.createAppDefaults()
            .staticField("android.app.Instrumentation", "mRecommendActivity")
            .reason("Instrumentation would leak com.android.internal.app.RecommendActivity (in framework.jar) in Meizu FlymeOS")
            .build();
LeakCanary.install(application, DisplayLeakService.class, excludedRefs);
```